# Is pre-compiling coffeescript faster than coffee-script/register?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

In a node.js app written with coffeescript it is typical to start of with something like `require('coffee-script/register');` to compile to JavaScript on the fly.

Besides for the couple of milliseconds at startup when the app compiles and then runs, are there any other performance drawbacks compared to pre-compiling and then distributing the JavaScript code ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the require for nodejs. `node script.coffee` works just fine.

A benchmark comparaison: https://blog.ashworth.in/coffeescript-performance-and-benchmarks/ Obviously the precompiled code is faster than compiling on the fly. I think it's always better to compile your CS code. CoffeeScript only benefits the developer (readability, shorter code...), you don't need that in production.

Comment: Those benchmarks are for a script that ends. In my case it's a long time running process (in docker in my case). I know that it takes longer to start up but my question is that if it has, is there anything I should watch out for that might be slower. For instance, might requiring certain packages compile every time etc.

Comment: How do you get `node script.coffee` working? I've not seen that.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `coffee script.coffee` to launch without compiling (it probably does in background but it's perfect for testing). I was confusing with `nodemon` wich works with coffee files. @Jason Prawn: I think there is cache or something so after compiling once, I doubt it compiles everytime you require a script..